# FOSUserBundle Registration Bug

Tags: fosuserbundle

I am having a problem with FOSUserBundle when a new user registers.

Right after registration, everything seems fine, i see the notice:

```
The user has been created successfully
papi@gmail.com
```

and :

```
Congrats papi@gmail.com, your account is now activated.
```

Then, if I click on any link, for example "Homepage", I see "Sign in/Sign up " as if I am not signed in anymore. I think after registration the user is supposed to stay signed in. Also, I don't have the rights of authenticated users, it is as if i am not signed in.

So if I try to sign in at this point (after having registered), I see the login/password prompt, but at the same time I see the notice:

```
papi@gmail.com Logout
```

It seems that I am at the same time signed in (notices) and not signed in (behaviour of the website). There is an inconsistency in the behaviour of FOSUserBundle.

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this problem?
I am not sure which  configuration file I should post here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug. You can find the fix on github there:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/578

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried updating to the latest version of FOSUserBundle : didn't solve the issue.
Than I did something bad : changed the code in vendor directory as described in the patch, but even this doesn't solve the problem.
What am I doing wrong ?